# Error: Rails command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a new Rails project in a directory, say Desktop (`rails new project1`). After that, I ran the following command:

```
rails server
```

Then, the project1 was running on localhost.

After that, I made another directory with name (project1) in another location. I copied all the files from the previous location to new location. After that, when I ran the following command:

```
rails server
```

I got the following error message:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system.
```

But it is working in the previous directory. How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you set your path correctly in the terminal after moving the project1 to another location?

Comment: You don't give any information about your environment.  Anyhow, type `Rails is not currently installed on this system.` in the search box at the top and you will find many threads with answers depending on environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are totally new to Rails development and System administration it is rather complicated in the beginning. I recommend any kind of Rails tutorial to you for examply by [Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) .

As Graeme McLean points out you somewhen understand that there is information about your environment needed to help you.

Most likely the requirements you need to be set up are not set up in the place you did copy your rails project as Pavan and Thaha kp pointed out.